# Read a JSON File using silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I need to read a JSON file from my local folder. Is it possible using WebClient?

Here's the code I currently have:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers["Content-Type"] =  "application/json";
        client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
        string url = "file - Copy.json";
        client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative));

}

private void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(e.Result);
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();

}
```

On execution, it throws a `TargetInvocationException`.

What's causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity, Touched up grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be done with some minor changes:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
    string url = @"C:\Users\YourNameHere\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestingApp\TestingApp\Copy.json";
    client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));
}

private static void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(e.Result);
    string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Basically you need to have the full path to the .json file and change the UriKind to Absolute.  The example above works fine.

Good luck!

Comment: I have another issue.  I need to download "http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/javascriptkit.json" through WCF service.  I used the same WebClient code, with the mentioned url, but it shows Target InvocationException. What could be the reason?

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977594/consuming-json-using-silverlight-throws-securityexception/28979845#28979845)